# set Font not applying to docx file created using POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I need to create a docx file in open office and its content needs to be in tamil Unicode font "latha" and its size is 10. But poi is creating docx file with "mangal" font and 12 font size. This docx file is working fine with Microsoft office.

My code:

```
        XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
        XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
        CTPPr ppr = paragraph.getCTP().getPPr();
        if (ppr == null) {
            ppr = paragraph.getCTP().addNewPPr();
        }
        CTSpacing spacing = ppr.isSetSpacing() ? ppr.getSpacing() : ppr.addNewSpacing();
        spacing.setAfter(BigInteger.valueOf(0));
        spacing.setBefore(BigInteger.valueOf(0));
        spacing.setLineRule(STLineSpacingRule.AUTO);
        spacing.setLine(BigInteger.valueOf(240));
        run.setFontFamily("Latha");
        run.setText(replaceAll2);
        run.getCTR().getRPr().getRFonts().setHAnsi("Latha");
        run.setFontSize(10);
```

Comment: Sir. I too having this issue. Someone please answer for this question

Comment: Which version of POI do you use?

Comment: poi-3.10.jar - I used this jar and its supporting jars